# WPF binding failure with AvalonDock Theme

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, avalondock

I'm using AvalonDock for my WPF Application and want to use data binding for changing the theme.

**ViewModel:**

```
    private Theme _AvalonDockTheme = new ExpressionDarkTheme();
    public Theme AvalonDockTheme
    {
        get
        {
            return _AvalonDockTheme;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_AvalonDockTheme != value)
            {
                _AvalonDockTheme = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("AvalonDockTheme");
            }
        }
    }
```

**XAML:**

```
<xcad:DockingManager AllowMixedOrientation="True"
        Theme="{Binding Source={StaticResource DockTheme}}" 
        x:Name="_dockingManager">
    <!-- some content -->
</xcad:DockingManager>
```

Whe I use this I get the following error message:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.Themes.ExpressionDarkTheme' BindingExpression:Path=MainViewModel.AvalonDockTheme; DataItem='App' (HashCode=47182344); target element is 'CollectionViewSource' (HashCode=42887454); target property is 'Source' (type 'Object')
```

I don't understand why the binding fails. The binding source and target are both of type Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.Themes.Theme but the error message says that the target element is of type CollectionViewSource. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this question:

[Binding a CollectionViewSource within a DataTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3358350/binding-a-collectionviewsource-within-a-datatemplate)

If that doesn't help, please provide DockTheme resource definition.

Comment: Thank you. You opened my Eyes. It was a copy-paste-mistake. I have declared the resource as a CollectionViewSource because I used this for a List in another window. I have controlled this resource much times but I haven't seen it. No I have changed it to a DataContext.